# How do i split each row using powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I'm trying to insert an table from 1 database to another (rows) using powershell. I already know how to get the data out but when i try to insert it into a new table I get an error that the string is too long (I think it means that i am trying to put all the data into an new row). I already searched the web for an answer. The only thing I could find is a command `-split` but then i need something to split with and the data is only numbers.

below you will find the script.

```
   $query = “SELECT ZAMNIEUW.MACHINENAME  FROM ZAMNIEUW WHERE MACHINENAME  not in (SELECT PATCHGROEPEN.MACHINENAME FROM PATCHGROEPEN ) "
                $command = $con.CreateCommand()
                $command.CommandText = $query
                $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
                $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
                $table.Load($result)
                $format = @{Expression={$_.WAARDE_PCNAME};Label=”ID”;width=20}


   echo $table.MACHINENAME


                 $table| foreach {

$qu= " INSERT into  TESTZEN (MACHINENAME) VALUES('$table')"
$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $qu
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null     

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apperantly oracle does use something to split each row (;)

the code below

```
$query = “SELECT ZAMNIEUW.MACHINENAME  FROM ZAMNIEUW WHERE MACHINENAME  not in (SELECT PATCHGROEPEN.MACHINENAME FROM PATCHGROEPEN ) "
                    $command = $con.CreateCommand()
                    $command.CommandText = $query
                    $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
                    $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
                    $table.Load($result)
                    $format = @{Expression={$_.WAARDE_PCNAME};Label=”ID”;width=20}


              $tables =echo $table.MACHINENAME


                     $tables| foreach {

                                           $tables = $_ -split ';'
                                            $qu= " INSERT into  TESTZEN (MACHINENAME) VALUES('$tables')"
                                            $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
                                            $cmd.CommandText = $qu
                                            $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |out-null     







       }
```